# Removing the millisecond from the timestamp

Tags: plsql

I need to convert timestamp to date in PL SQL.
I get Input as '2016-08-01T09:16:47.000' from webservice, I require '8/01/2016 9:16:47 AM'.
**I take the input as VARCHAR2**.

**It can be "AM" or "PM"**.

I tried using  select TRUNC(to_timestamp('2016-08-01T09:16:47.000','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.ff3')) from dual; but the time part is removed.

Comment: Please show your actual code - what you posted would fail completely as in is not syntactically valid.

Comment: select TRUNC(to_timestamp('2016-08-01T09:16:47.000','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.ff3'))  from dual;

Comment: Question tag should be SQL so that one can give the best answer. Poorly tagged questions are not best answered,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select to_char(to_timestamp('08/01/2016 09:16:47.000000000 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF AM'),'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') from dual;
```

Edit:  This works for am or pm

```
select to_char(to_timestamp('08/01/2016 09:16:47.000000000 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF AM'),'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') from dual;
```

Comment: Upvote coz you had answered it at the first. Credit goes to you.

Comment: It can be "AM" or "PM".

Comment: It will work irrespective of AM or PM provided your input time is in AM orPM..Nothing is hardcoded here.

Comment: Also, if removing the 0 before the month and day is necessary use this 'fmMM/DD/YYYY fmHH:MI:SS AM'

Answer (score 1):

Your query:

```
select TRUNC(to_timestamp('2016-08-01T09:16:47.000','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.ff3'))
  from dual;
```

returns a `date` value.  How you display that is then a matter of what format mask you use to convert it to a string.  Without a format mask the default NLS setting will be used e.g. I get:

```
SQL> select TRUNC(to_timestamp('2016-08-01T09:16:47.000','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.ff3'))
     from dual;

TRUNC(TO_
---------
01-AUG-16
```

becaiuse my NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting is currently 'DD-MON-RR'.  Using an explicit format mask:

```
  1  select TO_CHAR( TRUNC(to_timestamp('2016-08-01T09:16:47.000','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.ff3')
  2                  'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM')
  3*   from dual;

TO_CHAR(TRUNC(TO_TIMES
----------------------
2016-08-01 12:00:00 AM
```

That shows that using `trunc` was wrong as it removed the time altogether.  So:

```
  1  select TO_CHAR( to_timestamp('2016-08-01T09:16:47.000','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.ff3'),
  2                  'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM')
  3*   from dual;

TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP('
----------------------
2016-08-01 09:16:47 AM
```

Note this works for PM times also:

```
  1  select TO_CHAR( to_timestamp('2016-08-01T13:16:47.000','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.ff3'),
  2                  'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM')
  3*   from dual;

TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP('
----------------------
2016-08-01 01:16:47 PM
```

Comment: The "AM" is hard coded. It can also be "PM" in other cases.

Comment: You could simplify `to_timestamp('2016-08-01T13:16:47.000','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.ff3')` to `timestamp '2016-08-01 13:16:47'` to make the demo easier to read (that's if I'm reading it right).

Answer (score 0):

You should use to_char instead of trunc.
In your example, the correct operation would be - `to_char('08/01/2016 09:16:47.000000000 AM','dd:mm:yyyy hh:mi:ss am')`

Comment: Presumably some NLS setting is being assumed here? `'08/01/2016 09:16:47.000000000 AM'` is a character string not a timestamp, and if I run that I get `ORA-01722: invalid number`.